# Perspective transformation in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wonder if there is an easy way to do perspective transformation/distort/skewing to a simple plane (or even 3D object) in three.js? Preferably the mouse controls?

Something like in this example: jsfiddle.net/rjw57/A6Pgy/ except in three.js - fiddle is built directly in WebGL.

Otherwise, any idea how to reach the similar result?

Comment: the example you listed does not have distortion or skewing?

Comment: it does, the problem is, it gets really difficult to customize, since it written directly in WebGL, that's why I'm looking for a solution in three.js - it's much more approachable

Comment: @gaitat oh, I see you what you mean - you're right, distortion and skewing is something else, but it might help somebody in the future looking for something similar

Comment: @martin Did you find a solution to this? Also looking for the same.

Comment: @user2424495 not really, in the end we used the ImageMagick and it’s various transformation functions.